# Redirect based on $.getJSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, time

Sorry to seem a complete noob with jquery/ajax, but I am :)
I just started php 6 months ago, so I am struggling with a small script:

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
  try {
      setinterval(function() { 
          $.getJSON('check-session.php', function(data) { 
               if(!data) { redirect } 
          }); 
      }, 30000);
  }
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

This is what I did so far and I am totally stuck. Basically what I want it to do is, in case check-session.php returns logout I want to redirect to logout.php. I want it to check if check-session.php returns logout every 30 seconds in this case.
That is all.. Can someone please help me or put me in the right direction?

Comment: What does `check-session.php` return when the user isn't logged in? An empty json?

Answer (score 1):

Try window.location.href to redirect

```
try {
    setinterval(function () {
        $.getJSON('check-session.php', function (data) {
            if (!data) {
                window.location.href = 'logout.php';
            }
        });
    }, 30000);
}
```